# kafka connect connector doesn't start automatically

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a Kafka Connect source and sink connector for putting data into Kafka and taking it back out.

I am running Kafka and Kafka Connect using docker-compose which runs connect in distributed mode. see that it finds my plugin when connect starts up, but it doesn't actually do anything unless I do a POST to the /connectors API, including the configuration in JSON.

I have a properties file with the configuration in it and I've tried putting it under /etc where I find similar properties files for the other plugins that are installed.

Am I missing a step when installing my plugin, or is it required to register the connector via the REST API before it will be assigned to workers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to configure Kafka Connect using the REST API when using distributed mode.

It's possible to script the creation of connectors though, using a Docker Compose like this:

```
  command: 
    - bash 
    - -c 
    - |
      /etc/confluent/docker/run & 
      echo "Waiting for Kafka Connect to start listening on kafka-connect ⏳"
      while [ $$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://kafka-connect:8083/connectors) -eq 000 ] ; do 
        echo -e $$(date) " Kafka Connect listener HTTP state: " $$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://kafka-connect:8083/connectors) " (waiting for 200)"
        sleep 5 
      done
      nc -vz kafka-connect 8083
      echo -e "\n--\n+> Creating Kafka Connect Elasticsearch sink"
      /scripts/create-es-sink.sh 
      sleep infinity
```

where `/scripts/create-es-sink.sh` is the REST call from `curl` in a file mounted locally to the container.

([source](https://rmoff.net/2018/12/15/docker-tips-and-tricks-with-ksql-and-kafka/))

Comment: So what's the point of having the properties files under /etc if I'm basically going to be sending in the configuration via REST anyway? :)

Comment: In case you want to run it in Standalone mode.

Comment: Gotcha. Seems silly that they don't have a way to just configure it automatically in distributed mode. Thanks!

Comment: @RobinMoffatt inside the container ( as you mentioned above) my listener does not return 200 and keeps returning 000. however if I check the listener outside the container the listener returns 200 and is ready. any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

You can install a Kafka connector before you start the distributed Connect worker using "confluent-hub install" as shown here: [Install Kafka connector manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61539968/install-kafka-connector-manually)).   However, I'm not sure what the magic is if you aren't using confluent-hub though.

Comment: All you need to do is to add a Kafka Connect compatible JAR (eg https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/kinesis-kafka-connector-msk/)  to the plugin.path of your docker image as in the strategy exposed by Robin above...

Comment: The above answer by Robin is a two step process as well, just scripted in Docker init: 1st: start connect app, 2nd: start connector (via create-es-sink.sh).  The aws link you provided is using standalone mode (not distributed) and appears to be AWS specific (and not helpful).   Even the confluent-hub approach simply flips the order, but still requires two steps (install connector then run connect).

Comment: Any non confluent-hub connector will be installed just the same way and be triggered automatically by your Worker once it is started and have the correspondent connector jar at the plugin.path ... if you are running a Kafka Connect cluster you do not need to do anything else and your connector , AWS or whatsoever, will be running in distributed mode nice and easy. I thought that was your question around the magic step :)