# Install Kafka connector manually

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm trying install twitter source connector and found the following links [link1](https://www.confluent.io/blog/using-ksql-to-analyse-query-and-transform-data-in-kafka/) and [link2](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/install.html). The first one shows how to install twitter source connector and the second generally how to install manually a connector (always Confluent Platform).

However I'm confused from the entire procedure. I followed the steps in [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html?utm_medium=sem&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=ch.sem_br.brand_tp.prs_tgt.confluent-brand_mt.mbm_rgn.emea_lng.eng_dv.all&utm_term=%2Bconfluent%20%2Bdocker&creative=&device=c&placement=&gclid=Cj0KCQjwka_1BRCPARIsAMlUmEpVa2SWWSb6TBtha7dIvCCRTOqZL7LdiQsj4cpM4I70q8XIUWpMhP0aAnnXEALw_wcB), and so far it's working fine. However since the twitter source connector is not in the  list of the Connector Hub it needs to be installed manually. According to link1, I clone a git repo somewhere - **Question**: where do I clone it? In the docker-compose.yml there are a bunch of services. In particular, a `docker-compose ps` after I spin up the yaml shows

```
       Name                    Command                  State                         Ports
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   broker            /etc/confluent/docker/run        Up             0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp
   connect           /etc/confluent/docker/run        Up             0.0.0.0:8083->8083/tcp, 9092/tcp
   control-center    /etc/confluent/docker/run        Up             0.0.0.0:9021->9021/tcp
   ksql-datagen      bash -c echo Waiting for K ...   Up
   ksqldb-cli        /bin/sh                          Up
   ksqldb-server     /etc/confluent/docker/run        Up (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8088->8088/tcp
   rest-proxy        /etc/confluent/docker/run        Up             0.0.0.0:8082->8082/tcp
   schema-registry   /etc/confluent/docker/run        Up             0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp
   zookeeper         /etc/confluent/docker/run        Up             0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp
```

I don't understand to which one of the above I should carry out the instructions of link1. Is it in the zookeeper, the broker or in the connect?  Any help is welcomed, please if someone has time to write out a few words around the steps in link1 more thoroughly, please feel free. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connectors are installed in Kafka Connect workers. They must be installed before the worker is started.

There is a newer version of that blog article, here: https://www.confluent.io/blog/stream-processing-twitter-data-with-ksqldb. Associated with that is a new demo, which you can find here: https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/tree/master/ksqldb-twitter

As part of the demo, it installs the twitter connector [at runtime](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/ksqldb-twitter/docker-compose.yml#L108). It does this by overriding the default command of the container image and instead runs the connector installation before running the connect worker:

```yaml
    command: 
      - bash 
      - -c 
      - |
        echo "Installing connector plugins"
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt jcustenborder/kafka-connect-twitter:0.3.33
        #
        echo "Launching Kafka Connect worker"
        /etc/confluent/docker/run & 
        #
        sleep infinity
```

Comment: Hi Robin, thank you very very much for your prompt response and nice answer (+1). I have one (perhaps silly) question. How can you install in docker the cloned repo before the worker has actually started? When you spin up the docker containers with docker-compose, isn't all the stack up and running, i.e. zookeeper, broker start automatically?

Comment: + I have to say I'm really impressed from your docker-compose.yml in your repo.

Comment: thanks again, I get the gist; to summarise for a sec, I need in the connect service of the docker-compose.yml to include the above, hence upon creation the twitter connector will be installed. Last two questions (I promise :)): **1.)** is my first comment true? i.e., that when spin up the docker, zookeeper and broker start automatically? **2.)** do I need in the above command to include the cloning of the  custenborder/kafka-connect-twitter:0.3.33 repo, or the above command includes that step too? Thanks for everything.

Comment: 1. Yes 2. No need to clone repo, that Docker Compose is entirely self-contained. You'd clone the repo only if you were manually building and installing it (which you're not)